# Two different ways of instantiation

Tags: javascript

This is not a "how to" question. I want to discuss two possible ways of instantiation in JavaScript to find pros and cons of each one.

First one:

```
function Counter() {
  this.counter = 0;
}

Counter.prototype.count = function() {
  this.counter += 1;
  return this.counter;
};

var counter = new Counter();

console.log("Counter: " + counter.count());
```

And the second:

```
var counter = new (function() {
  var counter = 0;
  this.count = function() {
    counter += 1;
    return counter;
  }
})();

console.log("Counter: " + counter.count());
```

**IMPORTANT NOTE: `counter` is supposed to be instantiated only once.**

The first one looks more structured but the second does not clutter the namespace with unnecessary `Counter` function.

What do you think? Should I consider these two pieces of code equivalent? Am I missing something?

---

BTW, I use the 2nd way at the moment. The reason I ask this question is that JSHint states that it's a "Weird construction." and proposes to delete `new` which apparently breaks the code.

Comment: How many instances of `counter` will be created?

Comment: what you are missing is that in the second code, one can't read the value of the counter without incrementing it as it is a lexically hidden variable.

Comment: @cheeken That boldfaced line below the code seems very clear to me.

Comment: @RobW If only SO had emoticons for blushing ... thanks.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that `counter` can be modified by an external source, at the first method (given the fact the both "classes" will only be initialized once).

At the first method, `counter` is "publicly" visible and editable property.
At the second method, `counter` is a local variable, which cannot be modified by anything outside the function.

```
counter = new Counter();
counter.count(); // 1
counter.count = 9001; // Not intended?
counter.count(); // 9002
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, one immediate difference is that you can call Counter() multiple times, in the first block of code; whereas in the second, the function is not assigned a name and returns straight to a variable, hence cannot be called again.

Answer (score 0):

No they are not equivalent. Consider the first one. It is more flexible because you can extend it using the prototype in the other part of your application. Whereas in the second one you will not be able to do it easily because you don't have the main class reference.

Comment: Actually, the second method can also be extended: `counter.constructor.prototype.newmethod = ....`.